# How to move yellow part with text down to the white, when enough height is available?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, media-queries

I would like to optimize my screen to mobile, so when orientation is portrait-like, I would move the yellow part with text down to the white spare area. Do I need `media query`? I couldn't manage to calculate the available height of the white area.

[image]

```
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex"
  }}
>
  <div
    style={{
      width: `100%`
    }}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        paddingTop: `58.14%`,
        background: "pink",
        position: "relative"
      }}
    >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style={{ background: "yellow" }}>
    <span style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}>Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

One way I tried is to add
`flexDirection: "column"` to the first `div`, and that makes the effect, I just do not know how to make the `media query` condition and check the white available space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `orientation` in a media query:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { 
  [... your CSS rules for portrait mode here ...]
}
```

Comment: ahh, Safari does not support it? Chrome yes. Do you have idea how to any apply it also when it is iPhone or iPad Safari in portrait mode?

Comment: Safari on MacOS doesn't seem to support it (strange...), but Safari on iOS does - according to https://caniuse.com/#search=orientation

Answer (score 1):

flex-direction column + wrapping can help to detect available space underneath.

```css
 .main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
  padding-bottom: 55%;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="pink"></div>
  <div class="yellow">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: as I am resinzing, your yellow area does not move down as running code snippet :(

Comment: @János Yes, it does if you preview full-page

Comment: nice, but not safari on mac :(

Comment: it does not work for me, on full screen yellow is always down, in mini always on the side

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.pink {
    width: 80%;
    background: pink;
}

.yellow {
    width: 20%;
    background: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .flexcontainer {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .pink {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .yellow {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="pink">Test</div>
  <div class="yellow">Text</div>
</div>
```

Yes, you certainly require `@media query` when you have to work with different screen sizes and orientation and you wouldn't want to put this logic inline on the elements.
You will need to determine at what width should the element occupy the full width.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to set rule based on aspect ratio? If height / width is bigger than .. use this code ..

Comment: Yes, that is also possible. I think you need to use sass though

Comment: but you skipped al the other details, aspect ratio etc ;)

Comment: My thoughts are that your height will have a static size and adjusts based on contents inside the elements. which means you have to set the height of the element too. or were you thinking of something different?